# How do I test for the version of XFIXES in my configure.ac when compiling my X Driver?

Tags: linux-device-driver, autotools, autoconf, xserver

I'm writing a video device driver for X, and it needs some features provided by the XFIXES Extension. Now, I'm pretty sure that all of my target versions of the X Server will have at least version 2 of XFIXES installed, but I'd really like to test for that in my configure.ac file to warn the user if they try to compile my driver for a really old version of the server or for one in which (for some reason) XFIXES wasn't included. Right now I'm just doing this:

```
# Essentially this is just supposed to check if the server currently supports
# V2 or better of the XFIXES protocol, and to define XFIXES if it does.
AC_CHECK_HEADER(X11/extensions/Xfixes.h,
    HAVE_XFIXES="yes"; 
    AC_DEFINE([HAVE_XFIXES],[1],[XFixes Proto Found]),,
    [#include <X11/Xlib.h>])
# should have a better test for this
if test "x${HAVE_XFIXES}" = "xyes"; then
  AC_DEFINE([XFIXES],[1],[XFixes >= 2.0])
fi
```

Comment: I've since discovered that the above completely fails to work on some installations, as the presence of the XFixes.h header only indicates the level of client-side support for XFIXES, not the server-side. So right now, I'm just #defining XFIXES to 1, and failing mysteriously when that's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
AC_CACHE_CHECK([for Xfixes >= 2.0], [foo_have_xfixes_2],
[AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
                [[#include <X11/Xlib.h>
                  #include <X11/extensions/Xfixes.h>]],
                [[#if !(XFIXES_MAJOR >= 2)
                  #error XFIXES_LT_2
                  #endif]])],
                [foo_have_xfixes_2=yes], [foo_have_xfixes_2=no])])

if test "x${foo_have_xfixes_2}" = "xyes"; then
  AC_DEFINE([XFIXES],[1],[XFixes >= 2.0])
else
  AC_MSG_WARN("XFixes >= 2.0 not present")
fi
```

EDIT -- I now kinda get the problem.  We'll build on the initial solution here.
Now that I know we cannot use XFIXES_MAJOR (or something like it), use the struct definition for a struct you care about itself as the test.  For this example I'll assume the struct is XFixesCursorImage since it has some new components (e.g., *name*) when XFIXES_MAJOR >= 2.  Hopefully, a valid server header defining the same struct will also have those new components:

```
AC_CACHE_CHECK([for Xfixes >= 2.0], [foo_have_xfixes_2],
[AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
                [[#include <???>
                  XFixesCursorImage bar;]],
                [[bar.name = "bar";]])],
                [foo_have_xfixes_2=yes], [foo_have_xfixes_2=no])])

if test "x${foo_have_xfixes_2}" = "xyes"; then
  AC_DEFINE([XFIXES],[1],[XFixes >= 2.0])
else
  AC_MSG_WARN("XFixes >= 2.0 not present")
fi
```

The include header should now be the *server* version of the header.  The idea is that the server header where XFIXES_MAJOR < 2 will *not* have that component and compiling it will fail.  If that assumption is violated, this approach won't work either.

Comment: Those headers only exist if one has included libx11 development packages, which are client-side. It seems very strange to require someone to install a client-side package in order to compile a server-side driver which cannot actually use that package.

Comment: I awarded the bounty to this answer since it looks like it would actually work, even if its sub-optimal.

Comment: After reading your question more carefully, I agree that this code is probably not what you are after.  So your code doesn't depend on _anything_ in Xfixes.h?  Not even the struct sizes?

Comment: Oh, I depend on the struct sizes all right, and Xfixes.h looks like a good place to get them from... except that you are NOT supposed to include client-side headers in server-side X projects like drivers because they incompatible define the same types.

Comment: So...the server-side header file defines a struct (also defined in Xfixes.h) that you need but also doesn't set up XFIXES_MAJOR (or something similar) in a way that you could test for it?  Ouch.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly my problem.

Comment: OK...We'll have to adjust the AC_LANG_PROGRAM call a little:

Comment: ...it actually ended up being a lot more than the comment could bear, so I edited the answer.

Comment: Alas, your solution still doesn't work, because XFIXES>=2 is an INPUT to the header file. If true I need to define something like _XFIXES so the structs will include the extra fields, otherwise they won't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`AC_CHECK_FUNC`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Generic-Functions.html) to check for the presence of specific functions in a library. You must have previously run `AC_CHECK_LIB` on that library for this to work.

Comment: Alas, I don't need to check for the presence of a function in a library. XFIXES does define protocol elements for the X server, but the server is not a library. XFIXES also changes the size of certain structures, which I could check for, but the header files require the current version of XFIXES to be set before #including them... which is what I'm trying to figure out how to do.